# Swift Animation To 'Throw' Image to Center of Screen

Tags: ios, swift, animation

So I was playing around with animations tonight and trying to code the one I had in mind. So I have these two UIImageViews in opposite corners and I want them to go to the center of the screen (over the course of say, two seconds). I don't want the animiation to be linear though, I want it to be a trajectory motion. I tried the `CGAffineTransformation` struct to transform my images, but I don't  think that was what I was looking for because the transformation is linear movement. I have only been working with animations for a couple of hours and I don't know much. I know you can animate with a spring effect, but how would I get the image to spring vertically instead of horizontally?

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to create this animation, or if I have to create physics properties on the images and tinker around with it for awhile. If none of this is clear, here is image that might help (pardon my bad MS paint skills lol). So the bottom left image is the red/orange path and I want it shoot up and reach the center. The same idea applies for the top right (green); I'm fine with the image leaving the screen for a fraction of a second, as you can see.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var theImage: UIImageView! //top right image
    @IBOutlet weak var profilepic: UIImageView! //bottom left image

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            //don't know what goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to animate imageview to the center.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

  //Your imageview
  self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2)

  self.imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

 }, completion:nil)
```